# How to change the color of HandConnections in Media pipe?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, mediapipe

I was learning MediaPipe from some Tutorials and notices that the color of the HandConnection was White.
How do I change the color of the HandConnections from white ---> green??
Here is my code:

```
import cv2 
import mediapipe as mp
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands(static_image_mode=False, max_num_hands=2, min_detection_confidence = 0.4, min_tracking_confidence=0.5)
# Parameters,
""" 
static_image_mode, takes a boolean value. if True, It will track at all times (Not Recommended)
max_num_hands, Takes a Ineteger. Max Hands in a Capture
min_detection_confidence, Takes a float (0 --> 1). Min Confidence for static_image_mode to operate if False (Detection)
min_tracking_confidence, Takes a float (0 --> 1). Min Confidence for static_image_mode to operate if False (Tracking)
"""

mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

while True:
    success, img = cap.read() # Succes representing if image captured
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Changing format

    results = hands.process(imgRGB)
    # print(results)
    # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

    # print(success)
    cv2.imshow('Image', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(65) == ord('e'):
        break
        
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # Must
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit the colour in the `draw_landmarks()` function in `drawing_utils.py`

In this line

```
cv2.line(image, idx_to_coordinates[start_idx],
         idx_to_coordinates[end_idx], drawing_spec.color,
         drawing_spec.thickness)
```

just change `drawing_spec.color` to a tuple that represents your RGB colour of choice - e.g. (255,255,255) would be white:

```
cv2.line(image, idx_to_coordinates[start_idx],
         idx_to_coordinates[end_idx], (255, 255, 255),
         drawing_spec.thickness)
```